# Generate UI from a string

Tags: android, android-layout

Suppose I have an application that receives an Android UI layout XML in the form of a string from a web service. Say For Example:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/main_relative">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there anyway, that I could pass the Xml layout as string and receive the UI as output?

Comment: Yes. Use it by passing it to `setContentView()`. But then your code must be able to use the Views which are inside the layout. And if the layout differs from time to time, you must handle all the cases. Or if the layout is always the same, then it makes no sense to have it downloaded from a web site.

Comment: Hey Rotwang..! Nice to get you. could you elaborate with an example.

Comment: Ho do you associate a layout file to an Activity or a Fragment? By using `setContentView()`, at any moment (after the object has been created) - not necessarily in the `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` method.